# Jquery won't append <textarea> value to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. 
Just trying to copy the content of the  with the id txtarea to the div with the id rslt. Hope someone can shed some light:

```
    <title>Targil 2</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Write here:</p>
    <input type="text" id="bx" />
    <br />
    <p>and here:</p>
    <textarea cols="100" rows="8" id="txtarea"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="btn">GO</button>
    <script>
        $('#btn').click(function () {

            $("#txtarea").val().appendTo("#rslt");
        }
        );
    </script>
    <hr />
    <div id="rslt">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is a **String value**, but `.appendTo()` expects a **selector** reference (jQuery Object), therefore this **error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: **$(...).val(...).appendTo is not a function**

Use `.text()` or `.html()` instead

```html
<body>

<p>Write here:</p>
<input type="text" id="bx" />
<br>
<p>and here:</p>
<textarea cols="100" rows="8" id="txtarea"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="btn">GO</button>
<hr>
<div id="rslt"></div>


<!-- Scripts before </body> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $("#rslt").html( $("#txtarea").val() );
});
</script>

</body>
```

Additionally, make sure you place your `<script>` tags right before the closing `</body>` tag!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="rslt">
<span class="rstl">
</div>

$('#btn').click(function() {
$(".rslt").text($("#txtarea").val());
});
```

The div tag is not for the text like p , span etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#rslt').append($('#txtarea').val());
});
```

The reason appendTo does not work in this case is because appendTo needs to be called on a DOM element, not a string.